# Vaadin Designer hangs on startup

Tags: vaadin, designer

When I try to open an html template, a message appears "Please wait, loading view" and will just hang there.  Environment:

- M1 Mac on MacOS Monterey
- IntelliJ 2022.1
- Vaadin Designer 4.6.16
- Vaadin Framework 23.0.8

Any help in troubleshooting this issue would be appreciated.  I'm unable to find any log that shows what may be happening. I see others may be having a similar issue but there is no response from Vaadin support (https://github.com/vaadin/designer/issues/2435).

Additional Data:
Found something in the log that might be of help:

`2022-05-04 09:25:26,082 [38535031]   INFO - o.e.j.s.Server - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT 2022-05-04 09:25:26,083 [38535032]   INFO - o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3ac67ccc{/,null,AVAILABLE} 2022-05-04 09:25:26,084 [38535033]   INFO - o.e.j.s.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@7b0458a0{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:62226} 2022-05-04 09:25:26,084 [38535033]   INFO - o.e.j.s.Server - Started @25812811ms 2022-05-04 09:25:26,084 [38535033]   INFO - c.v.d.s.EditorApplicationServer - Remote preview available on http://192.168.86.176:62226. Designer running on http://localhost:62226. 2022-05-04 09:25:26,149 [38535098]   INFO - c.v.d.s.f.NodeProcessBuilder - Starting node process: node ./dist/server.js --rootPath=/Users/.../Development/.../src/.../node_modules --port=60389 --hostPid=39360 2022-05-04 09:26:24,719 [38593668]   WARN - c.v.d.i.u.PsiUtil - Multiple PSIs have been found for the class com.vaadin.flow.theme.lumo.Lumo. First found will be used. 2022-05-04 09:26:24,783 [38593732]   WARN - c.v.d.s.ProjectServlet - Request for /frontend/src/views/voucher/null returned 404 2022-05-04 09:27:24,825 [38653774]   WARN - o.e.j.w.j.a.JsrEvents - Unable to report throwable to websocket (no @OnError handler declared): com.vaadin.designer2.server.FlowWebSocket java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout on Read at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onReadTimeout(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:592) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractConnection.java:178) at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillInterestedFailed(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:538) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.failed(AbstractConnection.java:289) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.onFail(FillInterest.java:138) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.onIdleExpired(AbstractEndPoint.java:173) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)`

Comment: The ticket is about Designer 4.6.15. Version 4.6.16 is supposed to work with IntelliJ versions newer than 2021.3.3, see: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9519-vaadin-designer/versions If it is still not working, you probably have different issue.

Comment: @TatuLund understood.  How can I dig into the issue to figure out what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Designer 4.6.17. Installing IntelliJ Idea x86 the Designer works, installing aarch does not work. Vaadin should fix it, it seems an issue due to the architecture port